# Custom Entity interacting with view

Tags: views, entities

I have tried to create a custom entity in Drupal. It is working fine for now, but a lot of work needs to be done. I want the fields in the base table of the entity and the fields that I have added from the manage fields to be shown in the View Creation UI.

I tried to Google and found that I have to use the EntityDefaultViewsController but it is not working.

I have attached the module that I tried to create.

Any suggestion will be of great help.

Comment: Did you use EntityAPI module to create the entity?

Comment: Yes I have used it. It is some what like this
<?php
function contact_entity_info() {
  $return['contact'] = array(
    'label' => t('Contact'),
    'controller class' => 'ContactController',
    'views controller class' => 'EntityDefaultViewsController', 
    'uri callback' => 'contact_uri',
    'base table' => 'contact',
    'fieldable' => TRUE,
    'entity keys' => array(
      'id' => 'contactid',
      'bundle' => 'type',
      'label' => 'title',
     ),
    'bundle keys' => array(
      'bundle' => 'type',
    ),
    'static cache' => TRUE,
    'bundles' => array(),
  );

Comment: Could you please update your question including the above info as well as additional info.